Terraform, Azure and the CAF Enterprise Scale Module. My issue is in the management folder when trying to re-naming resources in the advanced block
My issue is in management folder then in the settins.managment file and finlly in the the advanced block I am re-naming the data collection rule and the  change tracking keeps giving me a error. Everything else works but the change tracking is giving me this error.
│ Error: Duplicate object key
│
│   on .terraform/modules/alz/locals.management.tf line 65, in locals:
│   63:   azurerm_monitor_data_collection_rule_management = {
│   64:     for resource in module.management_resources.configuration.azurerm_monitor_data_collection_rule :
│   65:     resource.resource_id => resource
│   66:     if resource.managed_by_module
│   67:   }
│     ├────────────────
│     │ resource.resource_id is "/subscriptions/**********/resourceGroups/rg-obs-plz-mgt-dev-uks/providers/Microsoft.Insights/dataCollectionRules/dcr-ct-plz-mgt-dev-uks-001"
│
│ Two different items produced the key
│ "/subscriptions/**************/resourceGroups/rg-obs-plz-mgt-dev-uks/providers/Microsoft.Insights/dataCollectionRules/dcr-ct-plz-mgt-dev-uks-001"
│ in this 'for' expression. If duplicates are expected, use the ellipsis
│ (...) after the value expression to enable grouping by key.
╵
##[warning]Can't find loc string for key: TerraformPlanFailed
##[error]Error: TerraformPlanFailed 1

All other resources are re-naming correctly/ not giving me any errors and if I comment out the change tracking it will run but not re-name it, has anyone come across or more importantly solved this issue before.
        azurerm_data_collection_rule = {
          management = {
            vminsights = {
              name = "dcr-vw-${var.zone}-${var.environment}-uks-001"
            },
            change_tracking = {
              name = "dcr-ct-${var.zone}-${var.environment}-uks-001"
             },
             defendersql = {
              name = "dcr-def-${var.zone}-${var.environment}-uks-001"
             }
          }
        }



Terraform, Azure and the CAF Enterprise Scale Module

The duplicate key issue arises when youre using 'for' in terraform configuration and in the same place youre tring to rename the rules.
Because of new name it leads to new resource id ultimately you ended by facing duplicate key issue.  This resource id should be unique. careful handling of the resources to ensure that no duplicate keys are generated.
I tried removing 'for' from the configuration and provisioned separately I was able to provision the requirement as expected.
Configuration:
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
.
.
resource "azurerm_monitor_data_collection_rule" "dcr_vminsights" {
  name                        = "dcr-vw-${var.zone}-${var.environment}-uks-001"
  location                    = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  data_collection_endpoint_id = azurerm_monitor_data_collection_endpoint.example.id

  destinations {
    log_analytics {
      workspace_resource_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.example.id
      name                  = "vminsights-log-analytics-destination"
    }

    event_hub {
      event_hub_id = azurerm_eventhub.example.id
      name         = "vminsights-eventhub-destination"
    }

    storage_blob {
      storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.example.id
      container_name     = azurerm_storage_container.example.name
      name               = "vminsights-storage-destination"
    }

    azure_monitor_metrics {
      name = "vminsights-metrics-destination"
    }
  }

  data_flow {
    streams      = ["Microsoft-Perf"]
    destinations = ["vminsights-log-analytics-destination"]
  }

  data_sources {
    performance_counter {
      name                        = "vminsights-cpu-performance"
      streams                     = ["Microsoft-Perf"]
      counter_specifiers          = ["\\Processor(_Total)\\% Processor Time"]
      sampling_frequency_in_seconds = 15
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_data_collection_rule" "dcr_change_tracking" {
  name                        = "dcr-ct-${var.zone}-${var.environment}-uks-001"
  location                    = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  data_collection_endpoint_id = azurerm_monitor_data_collection_endpoint.example.id

  destinations {
    log_analytics {
      workspace_resource_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.example.id
      name                  = "change_tracking-log-analytics-destination"
    }

    event_hub {
      event_hub_id = azurerm_eventhub.example.id
      name         = "change_tracking-eventhub-destination"
    }

    storage_blob {
      storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.example.id
      container_name     = azurerm_storage_container.example.name
      name               = "change_tracking-storage-destination"
    }

    azure_monitor_metrics {
      name = "change_tracking-metrics-destination"
    }
  }

  data_flow {
    streams      = ["Microsoft-Perf"]
    destinations = ["change_tracking-log-analytics-destination"]
  }

  data_sources {
    performance_counter {
      name                        = "change_tracking-cpu-performance"
      streams                     = ["Microsoft-Perf"]
      counter_specifiers          = ["\\Processor(_Total)\\% Processor Time"]
      sampling_frequency_in_seconds = 15
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_data_collection_rule" "dcr_defendersql" {
  name                        = "dcr-def-${var.zone}-${var.environment}-uks-001"
  location                    = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  data_collection_endpoint_id = azurerm_monitor_data_collection_endpoint.example.id

  destinations {
    log_analytics {
      workspace_resource_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.example.id
      name                  = "defendersql-log-analytics-destination"
    }

    event_hub {
      event_hub_id = azurerm_eventhub.example.id
      name         = "defendersql-eventhub-destination"
    }

    storage_blob {
      storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.example.id
      container_name     = azurerm_storage_container.example.name
      name               = "defendersql-storage-destination"
    }

    azure_monitor_metrics {
      name = "defendersql-metrics-destination"
    }
  }

  data_flow {
    streams      = ["Microsoft-Perf"]
    destinations = ["defendersql-log-analytics-destination"]
  }

  data_sources {
    performance_counter {
      name                        = "defendersql-cpu-performance"
      streams                     = ["Microsoft-Perf"]
      counter_specifiers          = ["\\Processor(_Total)\\% Processor Time"]
      sampling_frequency_in_seconds = 15
    }
  }
}

deployment:


Refer:
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/monitor_data_collection_rule
